# How to reset admin password in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I want to use the status manager on my local installation of Tomcat 7 but it asks for a password and I can't recall what it is. How do I reset it without reinstalling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to look at your `conf\tomcat-users.xml` file. Note, as it is says in that file you'll need to have a user with the role `"manager-gui"` to use those tools.

So the following line would work:

```
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml` file.
The password should be visible after the `keystorepass` tag.

You can test it using the `list` command like this:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore .keystore
```